# Resolving pre-existing selection for a Lookup Field after a new Custom Filter has been added

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm working in Microsoft Dynamics 365 and have a problem with the Custom Filters for Lookup Fields.

Right now, when a value is selected for one Lookup Field, this calls some JavaScript that builds a CustomFilter for another Lookup field. This works exactly as it should. The problem though is that occasionally there is a value that was already entered in this filtered Lookup that is no longer relevant, and I'm trying to figure out how best to handle this.

Example:
If Option A is selected, values 1, 2, 3, 4 will appear in the filtered lookup.
If Option B is selected, values 3, 4, 5, 6 will appear in the filtered lookup.

The client is requiring that the filtered lookup not be blanked out if the entered value in the filtered lookup field is still relevant. In the case of the above example, that would be values 3 and 4, but these exact over-lapping values could change down the road so I'm not about to hard-code the solution.

I'm not seeing any quick way to accomplish this. I would rather not perform a separate search based on the filter as that will be extremely time consuming for me to put together given how things have been built up to this point. Also, Dynamics seems to resolve the selection based on pre-filtered criteria, which doesn't help.

Any thoughts or idea?

Comment: I feel this is extreme edge case to solve :)

Answer (score 0):

I gave a second thought about this. You have 3 options to try.

1. store the selected value from lookup2 on form load/on change of lookup2 in a local variable, then on change of lookup1 fetch the available options based on prefilter query & cross check with local variable. If it’s still a relevant option, then set the lookup2 with local variable value
2. we can try to stop clearing the lookup2 , not quite sure if it’s possible. Like hooking the onchange of lookup1 & preventDefault when the previously selected option is still a relevant option
3. convince the client & train the end user to choose lookup2 again as in this is not worth the effort